# Store Tf-idf matrix and update existing matrix on new articles in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have a pandas dataframe with column `text` consists of `news articles`. Given as:-

```
text
article1
article2
article3
article4
```

I have calculated the Tf-IDF values for articles as:-

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
matrix_1 = tfidf.fit_transform(df['text'])
```

As my dataframe is kept updating from time to time. So, let's say after calculating of-if as matrix_1 my dataframe got updated with more articles. Something like:

```
text
article1
article2
article3
article4
article5
article6
article7
```

As I have millions of articles and all I want to store a tf-IDF matrix of the previous article and updating the same with tf-IDF scores of the new article. Running the of-IDF code for all articles, again and again, would be memory consuming. Is there any way I can perform this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code but I feel that this should work.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

df = pd.DataFrame()
while True:
    if not len(df):
        # When you dataframe is populated for the very first time
        tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
        matrix_1 = tfidf.fit_transform(df['text'].iloc[last_len:])
        last_len = len(df)
    else:
        # When you dataframe is populated again and again
        # If you have to use earlier fitted model
        matrix_1 = np.vstack(matrix_1, tfidf.transform(df['text'].iloc[last_len:]))
        # If you have to update tf-idf every time which is kinda doesn't make sense
        matrix_1 = np.vstack(matrix_1, tfidf.fit_transform(df['text'].iloc[last_len:]))
        last_len = len(df)

    # TO-DO Some break condition according to your case
    #####
```

If the duration between dataframe updates is longer than you can use pickle on matrix_1 to store intermediate results.

However what I feel is using `tfidf.fit_transform(df['text'])` again and again on different inputs will not give you any meaningful results or may be I misunderstood. Cheers!!

Comment: How I can verify whether it storing values on existing matrix? What's `last_len`?

Comment: Well it should be fairly simple from the code. You can verify by checking the shape of matrix 1 after every iteration and last_len is the length checkpoint of the dataframe which can help you separate old and new articles in dataframe.

Comment: So, if initially I have 4 articles then what would be the `last_len` ? Then in next turn 3 more articles will also get added. So what would be `last_len` in that case?  Sorry, if its silly but I don't get it.

Comment: So for the very first time when your dataframe has 4 articles last_len will have 4(0-3 articles) as its value from this line of code `last_len = len(df)` and when 3 more articles are added to dataframe this line `df['text'].iloc[last_len:]` will select articles indexed as (4,5,6) and this line 'last_len = len(df)' will set last_len as 7. You should debug the code to understand this things.